trace of a matrix squared:a formula
Can someone explain to me why $$\operatorname{Tr}K^2=\sum_{\alpha,\beta} K_{\alpha\beta}K^{\alpha\beta}$$


What's fhe formula for matrix multiplication in index notation? I.e. if $C=AB$ then $C_\alpha^\beta=_\cdots$ ?

It's true that $\mbox{trace}(K^{T}K)=\sum_{i,j} K_{i,j}^{2}$.  If $K$ is symmetric, than $\mbox{trace}(K^{2})=\sum_{i,j}K_{i,j}^{2}$.  This can be shown using the formula for the matrix product.

What does $K^2$ actually mean? $K$ is a symmetric tensor of rank $2$, not a linear map.

@TedShifrin So $K^2$ is not a squaring index but rather the tensor rank dimension ?

No, no, it's a squaring index. But the question is how to make sense of that. You have to raise the indices on one copy and then contract the resulting tensor to take the trace. $K$ is not a matrix of a linear transformation.

It would be helpful to 1) indicate where this image is taken, and 2) indicate how $\mathbf{K}$ is defined.

@Semiclassical It's from the famous book Gravitation by Misner. I believe that $K$ is  a mere matrix.

@TedShifrin A detailed answer would be great.

No, $K$ is a $2$-tensor and not a "mere matrix." Read more carefully :) As others have said, if you pretend it is a matrix of a linear transformation and don't pay attention to where indices are, then, indeed, if $A=[a_{ij}]$, then $A^2 = [\sum_k a_{ik}a_{kj}]$ and $\text{tr}(A^2) = \sum_{i,k} a_{ik}a_{ki}$.

@TedShifrin I'm confused. If I pretend what you have said I shall not pretend (I.e. that $K$ is a mere matrix) then you've obtained the result we were seeking for, right ?

We use the metric tensor to calculate the trace of a $2$-tensor: If $A=[a_{ij}]$ is a $2$-tensor, then
$$\text{tr}(A) = \sum g^{ij}a_{ij}.$$
What we are doing is using the metric tensor to raise one index (i.e., turn the tensor into a (1,1)-tensor or linear map $\tilde A=[a_i^k]$ and then take the trace of that linear map):
$$a_i^k = \sum g^{kj}a_{ij}, \quad\text{and so}\quad  \text{tr}\,\tilde A = \sum a_i^i = \sum g^{ij}a_{ij}.$$
Now, to define the trace of $K^2$, we compute
$$\sum K_i^jK_j^i = \sum g^{j\ell}K_{i\ell}g^{im}K_{jm}.$$
But this is $\sum K_{i\ell}K^{\ell i}$ when we raise both indices and write
$K^{\ell i} = \sum g^{j\ell}g^{im}K_{jm}$. This is, of course, converting $K$ to the linear map $\tilde K$ and then taking $\text{tr}(\tilde K{}^2)$.
